Paste special option missing in Visual Studio 2022
I have Visual Studio 2022 version 17.10.4 version installed on my machine with ASP.NET and Web Tools but I don't see Paste special option under Edit menu, earlier this options exist in Visual Studio 2019.
I have to convert JSON to class. I can see various online tools but I don't want to use. can't this feature be enabled in Visual Studio 2022.

The command is shown only when you have a valid target for the paste special op. Does the current window contain a class code?

@Steve yes. it is C# class file

Then I don't know what happens. If I activate a cshtml file the command is not shown while with a .cs file I have it just under the "show clipboard history".

You can add 'Paste special' option to the index bar by following these steps:
“Tools” -> “Customize” -> “Commands” -> "Add Command…" -> “Edit” -> “Paste Special” -> “OK”

This is just menu addition. after addition, it is disabled. not of use because feature itself is not available

This option is presented in VS2022 for C#(*.cs) or VB(*.vb) code files, please see Paste JSON or XML as classes
You have this option presented in the Edit menu when you have an opened C#(*.cs) code file in the editor.
If you are missing this option at all from VS2022 then you might have skipped adding "Web Dev prerequisites" as is mentioned Web development Tools for VS2019. For VS2022 it seems to be included with "ASP.NET and web development prerequisites" since I have it available without "Web development tools for .NET Core 2.1" component checked and added:

